# Storing variable data for later use csv python 3.6.4 Spyder 3.2.7

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Hi Sorry to have to ask this but none of the tutorials are working and im getting errors for basic stuff.

I have a whole list of variables that get updated as my script runs. Getting error on line 18.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testcsv.csv'
```

So i would like to append the variables to the csv.
When they change append again.
And later when i restart the script assign the most recent variable data to the variables so I can pick up where i left off. I will also be using the data for plotting etc. Im having a bit of a hard time trying to find a simple easy and fast way to do this without heaps of code.

```
import csv

A = 1.1234
B = 0.8765
rate1 = 1.22323
rate2 = 1214.32

fields=[A, B, rate1, rate2]

with open('testcsv.csv','a') as csvf:
    spamwrite= csv.writer(csvf)
    spamwrite.writerow(fields)

with open ('testcsv.csv', newline='') as csvf:
    spamread = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamread:
        print (','.join(row))
```

I would just like to have the csv open and write new vals as i need to then close the csv upon exit of the script so i can minimise code.

Comment: seems like to you don't have permission to write to the file, check the file permissions.

Comment: Thats what i thought but it has full permissions